# Convert NSString to Int and then use that value to determine which text to display in a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I have my weather station app I am working on, it all works but the one thing I want to do is with the UV rating there is usually and word rating associated with the number. (Ex - UV rating is less then 3, word accompniing it "Low", between 3-6, "Medium" and etc...) 
How do I convert my NSString, which displays the value into and int and then assign a word based on the range in which that value falls in.

I know how I would do the comparing in Java but I do not know how to in swift.
This is what I was thinking for it ( sudocode, Java basedish):

```
METHOD()
if(this.UVrating() < 3)
println("Low")
```

First of course I need to convert the NSString to an int in order to do this. The NSString will always be an integer.

TL;DR -

1: Convert NSString to int

2: Depending on int value, update a UILabel with "Low" "Medium" "High" and "Extreme"

Low -> 0-3

Medium -> 4-6

High -> 7-10

Extreme -> 11+

Comment: You can convert text by `text.intValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below.

```
NSString *str = @"1"; // Here your string value which contains int value as string
int data = str.intValue;
```

then continue your code

```
if (data>=11) {
    NSLog(@"Extreme"); // here instead of nslog you can write code to change lable values
}else if (data<=10 && data>=7){
    NSLog(@"High");
}else if (data<=6 && data>=4){
    NSLog(@"Medium");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Low");
}
```

Update : SWIFT Version

```
    var strData:NSString = "1"

    var intValueOfString:Int = strData.integerValue

    if (intValueOfString>=11) {
        NSLog("Extreme") // here instead of nslog you can write code to change lable values
    }else if (intValueOfString<=10 && intValueOfString>=7){
        NSLog("High")
    }else if (intValueOfString<=6 && intValueOfString>=4){
        NSLog("Medium")
    }else{
        NSLog("Low")
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: I convert code in swift for you, I think this will solve the problem